# Why does a simple automation test with Appium fail?

Tags: react-native, automated-tests, appium, appium-android

I'm developing an application with React Native and I'm experiencing difficulties in test automation with the Appium framework.

I have never used the tool and my first goal is to check if the following element exists on the main screen. PS: the element exists.

```
<TouchableOpacity
  testID="test-login"
  accessibilityLabel="test-login"
>
    <Text>test login</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

In the project, I created the *test* folder with the *sample.test.js* file

```
const webdriverio = require('webdriverio');

const androidOptions = {
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'Chrome',
    allowInsecure: {},
    denyInsecure: {},
  },
  desiredCapabilities: {
    browserName: 'Chrome',
    path: '/wd/hub',
    port: 4723,
    platformName: 'Android',
    app:
      '/Users/xxx/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk',
    deviceName: 'xxx', // adb devices
    automationName: 'Appium',
    appPackage: 'XXX',
    launchActivity: 'XXX.MainApplication',
    chromeOptions: {w3c: false},
    ensureWebviewsHavePages: true,
    platformVersion: '8.0.0',
  },
};

describe('things', () => {
  let client;

  before(async () => {
    client = await webdriverio.remote(androidOptions);
  });

  it('test', async () => {
    //await client.elementByAccessibilityId('test-login');
    //client.elementsByAccessibilityId('test-login');
    await client.findElementsByAccessibilityId('test-login');
    //let elementsOne = await client.elementsByAccessibilityId('test-login');
    //let elementsTwo = await client.elements('id', 'test-login');
    //await client.elementByAccessibilityId('test-login').isClickable;
  });

  after(async () => {
    return await client.deleteSession();
  });
});
```

and run it with *node ./node_modules/.bin/mocha*.

The output is

```
things
INFO webdriverio: Initiate new session using the devtools protocol
INFO devtools: Launch Google Chrome with flags: --disable-extensions --disable-background-networking --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-sync --metrics-recording-only --disable-default-apps --mute-audio --no-first-run --disable-hang-monitor --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --password-store=basic --use-mock-keychain --disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages --disable-breakpad --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-ipc-flooding-protection --disable-renderer-backgrounding --enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess --disable-features=site-per-process,TranslateUI,BlinkGenPropertyTrees --window-position=0,0 --window-size=1200,900
INFO devtools: Connect Puppeteer with browser on port 51345
    1) test
    ✓ should create and destroy Android browser session
INFO devtools: COMMAND deleteSession()
INFO devtools: RESULT null

  0 passing (1s)
  1 failing

  1) things
        test:
      TypeError: client.findElementsByAccessibilityId is not a function
      at Context.it (test/sample.test.js:97:18)
      at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:126:23)
```

The android phone with the application in debug mode is connected to the computer.

I have tried snippets about it but without success.

Could you help me with the first step?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

The error says "TypeError: client.findElementsByAccessibilityId is not a function"

Which means the object returned from webdriverio.remote, doesn't have a findElementsByAccessibilityId function.

You should add something like this:

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(client));
```

or

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(client).filter(x => typeof client[x] == 'function'));
```

before the `client.findElementsByAccessibilityId` call to see what it actually contains.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Tom. I tried but the result does not change unfortunately.